# initWithNibName vs init - unexpected behaviour

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nib

I have noticed that when adding a viewController with interface builder and a nib,

That I don't have to call initWithNibName for it to pick up the associated nib, I can just call init!

Any idea why?

ie.

This:

```
NotificationManagementController *notificationView = [[NotificationManagementController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NotificationManagementController" bundle:nil andCurrentNotifications:nil];
```

and This:

```
NotificationManagementController *notificationView = [[NotificationManagementController alloc] init];
```

Both seem interchangeable....

Thus if I then call these line of code:

```
notificationView.delegate = self;
notificationView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentViewController:notificationView animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

I see all changes in the nib.

Comment: Take a look at the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/nibName): "if you do not specify a nib name, and do not override the loadView method in your custom subclass, the view controller searches for a nib file using other means. Specifically, it looks for a nib file with an appropriate name (without the .nib extension) and loads that nib file whenever its view is requested. (...)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NotificationManagementController *notificationView = [[NotificationManagementController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NotificationManagementController" bundle:nil andCurrentNotifications:nil];
```

is simply not neccessary, and even frowned upon by some (including me).

```
NotificationManagementController *notificationView = [[NotificationManagementController alloc] init];
```

is much cleaner (and safer) in that is hides implementation details, but will effectively call `initWithNibName:` behind the scenes.

I like to think of it this way:

```
- (id)init 
{
    self = [[NotificationManagementController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NotificationManagementController" bundle:nil andCurrentNotifications:nil];
    if (self)
    {
        // Initialization
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: sounds great! but what If I want to add further input parameters to my init method, initWithNibName is the only one exposed? So I was extending that, why is it bad to call withNibName?

Comment: [Because it breaks encapsulation](http://oleb.net/blog/2012/01/initWithNibName-bundle-breaks-encapsulation/)

Comment: @JohnWoods Extra input parameters can be added by adding custom `init`methods to your VC. Don't get me wrong lots of developers use `withNibName`, I just feel that it's better to use it once in another `init` method. If you were to change your Nib name for instance, having `withNibName` only called once makes refactoring a bit cleaner :)

Comment: Many thanks for that 'it break encapsulation' link, @albertamg!

Comment: By the way, if you do that in Xcode 7 (what the link with 'it break encapsulation' says), you will get 2 warnigs. Use this to silence the warnings http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25429685/turn-off-designated-initializer-checking-in-xcode-6

Comment: @Alex you are welcome! Btw, if you mark your init method as the new designated initializer, those warnings should go away: `- (instancetype)init NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;` (you will need to override `initWithCoder:` as well)