# Turn off designated initializer checking in Xcode 6

Tags: objective-c, xcode, suppress-warnings, designated-initializer

I'm getting the compile error:

```
error: convenience initializer missing a 'self' call to another initializer [-Werror,-Wobjc-designated-initializers]
```

Compile-checked designated initializers might be a good thing, but if I don't want deal with that right now, how can I turn this off?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Method 1

In your project:

1. Edit the build settings for your target (⌘-1, select project, or cf. [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/articles/EditingBuildSettings.html)).
2. Search for "Other warning flags".
   [image: up in here, yo]
3. Add `-Wno-objc-designated-initializers`.

You can also do some combination of this and `-Wobjc-designated-initializers` on a per file basis or with clang diagnostic pushes and pops (cf. @bandejapaisa's "Method 3" [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27146880/45813) below).

### Method 2

This method allows you to switch back and forth between Xcode 5 & 6, and also provides you a reminder to fix the designated initializer stuff.

For iOS development, put this in your `.pch` (precompiled header) file:

```
#ifdef __IPHONE_8_0
    // suppress these errors until we are ready to handle them
    #pragma message "Ignoring designated initializer warnings"
    #pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wobjc-designated-initializers"
#else
    // temporarily define an empty NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER so we can use now,
    // will be ready for iOS8 SDK
    #define NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER
#endif
```

The [analog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25554537) to `__IPHONE_8_0` for OS X 10.10 is `__MAC_10_10`.

### Why?

If you are interested in why these messages exist, you can check out [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24565513/45813)
or these [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Initialization/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010810-CH6-SW3).

Comment: Will this xcode build configuration violate Apple compliance or cause app rejection? Just a curiosity.

Comment: @Vijay I highly doubt it. Certainly not that I know of.

Comment: Literally the most annoying thing ever coming back to Obj-C code from Swift.

Answer (score 36):

Following on from Clay's answer..

### Method 3

You might want to suppress the warning on one occurrence, not all of them:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wobjc-designated-initializers"
- (instancetype) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
    if (self) {
        // do whatever I was doing....
    }
    return self;
}
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

EDIT:
However, I've only actually used this once myself. I find it the same amount (or a little more) effort just to do it properly if it's a single case. So flag up your constructor with NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER. And if it then complains about the init method not being overridden add an init method to your header with NS_UNAVAILABLE.

Comment: This is great @bandejapaisa, do you by chance have a list of where the error messages and their corresponding string like above are stored.  Is there a lookup table somewhere?

Comment: Good question. Did a quick search and didn't find any list on clang website or documentation. Did find this though: http://nshipster.com/clang-diagnostics/ which has a link at the bottom of the article to a site with a list - although it doesn't contain this particular error, so it can't be a definitive list.