# Analog to __IPHONE_8_0 for OS X 10.10

Tags: cocoa, preprocessor-directive, osx-yosemite

What's the analog to `#ifdef __IPHONE_8_0` for OS X 10.10?

I've RTM/STFI, enough at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#ifdef __MAC_10_10`

The `#define`s for the OS  versions are in `Availability.h`.